# Failure to Run Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat

I am attempting to run Postgresql locally on my computer. I am getting a bunch of errors when local.run.db=PostGresql in application properties. Error- JDBCURL is required with driver classname, error create bean with name datasource , unable to start embedded TOMCAT.
Ive been debugging for 24 hours I cant figure it out.

```
public class DataSourceConfig
{
    /**
     * The property from application properties. Defaults to H2
     */
  @Value("${local.run.db:h2}")
    private String dbValue;

    /**
     * A config var for the database link - defaults to nothing
     */
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url:}")
    private String dbURL;

    /**
     * The actual datasource configuration
     *
     * @return the datasource to use
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        if (dbValue.equalsIgnoreCase("POSTGRESQL"))
        {
            // Assume Heroku
            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            config.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            config.setJdbcUrl(dbURL);
            return new HikariDataSource(config);
        } else
        {
            // Assume H2
            String myURLString = "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb";
            String myDriverClass = "org.h2.Driver";
            String myDBUser = "sa";
            String myDBPassword = "";

            return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .username(myDBUser)
                    .password(myDBPassword)
                    .url(myURLString)
                    .driverClassName(myDriverClass)
                    .build();
        }
    }
}

@EnableJpaAuditing
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = "file:/c/Users/georg/Documents/ketodiet.properties",ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class DogdietappBeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DogdietappBeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the [tag:q] library

Comment: Is the value of `spring.datasource.url` a correct JDBC URI?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I believe so I made the spring.datasource.url in a file in notepad and I have it linked in the app here it is : SPRING.DATASOURCE.URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/geogeketo?password=password&sslmode=prefer&user=postgres

Comment: Configuration properties are actually case sensitive, therefore what you specified is not `spring.datasource.url`.